# Formatting output of CSV data?

Tags: python, format

I'm fairly new to python and made something that had this output: 
(The text is in a csv file so so:
1,A
2,B
3,C etc)

```
Number        Letter

1             A
2             B
3             C
26            Z
```

Unfortunately, I spent a good amount of time making it using a complicated method in which I manually made spaces like this:
**Updated Code rn**

```
fx = int(input('Number?\n'))
f=open('nums.txt','r')
lines=f.readlines()
line = lines[fx - 1]
with open('nums.txt','r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i >= 5: 
            break
        NUM, LTR, SMB = line.rsplit(',', 1)
        print(NUM.ljust(13) + LTR.ljust(13) + SMB)
```

How do I get it to make 3 columns? Right now it comes up with a

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

---

So is there a simpler method of achieving this that doesn't move the strings around like this:

```
Number        Letter

1             A
2             B
3             C
26             Z #< string moves with spaces.
```

Comment: use `format`...

Comment: If you're looking for fixed-width columns, don't you just want something like `'{:<13}{:<13}'.format(26, 'Z')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple alignment, you can use [`ljust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ljust) or [`rjust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rjust). There is also no need to read the entire file for each line you want to process:

```
with open('numberletter','r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i >= 5: 
            break
        number, letter = line.rsplit(',', 1)
        print(number.ljust(13) + letter)
```

For more complex output formatting, look at [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and the [formatting syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings)

Comment: What if I wanted to have 3 columns for example: 
Numbers     Letters     Symbols

Comment: You would apply `ljust` to the second column, as well. Or better, just use `rjust` on every column. Right alignment looks better in most cases, anyway ;-)

Comment: So would it just be 
       `NUM, LTR, SMB = line.rsplit(',', 1)`
                                                                                                              `print(NUM.ljust(13) + LTR.ljust(13) + SMB)`

Comment: Yeah, but `NUM, LTR, SMB = line.rsplit(',', 2)`, since you need two splits now...

Comment: Do you know how I can also add a string along with the file? Right now everytime I try do this: `print(NUM.ljust(13) + LTR.ljust(13) + SMB + 'test') ` the 'test' string moves to the first character of the output like this:

`test 26 z` instead of `26 test z`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `sys` module for that.

```
import sys
a=[1,"A"]
sys.stdout.write("%-6s %-50s " % (a[0],a[1]))
```

Comment: What does that have to do with `sys` apart from that you happen to be able to write to `sys.stdout`? The reason why this works has nothing to do with `sys` and everything with the (deprecated) string formatting operator `%`.

Comment: @L3viathan I think he put sys in there because the print function keeps printing new lines after each output and I requested output with no newlines.

Comment: @Yaya `print(s, end='')` does the same with less effort

Comment: For no newlines, add a `end=''` argument to your call to `print`.